# Send batch email to a very large list of addresses

Tags: php, list, email, phpmyadmin, mailing

I have a mailing of 30000 emails to sent.
Manish help me to implement a solution for which the main code is available below.
When I execute this code I have the following error message.
May you inform me how to solve it ?

//www.skills4all.net/manish/testmail.php //
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in /home/u903426621/domains/skills4all.net/public_html/manish/testmail.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/u903426621/domains/skills4all.net/public_html/manish/testmail.php on line 21

Comment: The term [mailing list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailing_list) is often used with a specific meaning and sending messages to the list is identical to sending regular mail. I suppose you really mean to send batch email to a very large list of addresses. You may want to edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

I have a mailing of 30000 emails. I am looking for a free solution to be able to send email to all the contain in this mailing list.

```
I don't think there is any SMTP service for free for this amount of emails.
```

Is it possible to code in PHP the solution ? Is it easier to do with another coding langages ?

```
This is not a programming or programming language issue, this is SMTP service issue.
```

Is there any free software which would give you this possibility ?

```
Again, this is not a software issue, this is a service issue
```

You need to get some SMTP email send out service for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have option for cron job then :

Add one column in your email database. say `email_sent` with type `smallint` It will add value as 0 by default.

Now create a php script which will send email. In this script, select three (with limit clause) rows everytime with condition `where email_sent='0'` After sending email to email-ids in these three rows, update `email_sent='0'` to `email_sent='1'` in that rows.

Now set your cronjob to run per minute. So you can send 180 emails per hour. Generally shared hosting allows 200 / 250 emails per hour. (** of course as your table contains 30,000 rows, it will take around 6 days to send emails to all but as you needed free option, then some compromise is also needed )

Now second part, create another php script for cronjob to run every day / weekly etc. which will reset `email_sent='1'` to `email_sent='0'` in whole database table. So you can send new emails again with same php scripts.

Comment: Hi Manish ! I am interested by your proposal. I am beginner on this technologies - any how to ? website ? blog ? on which one there's some info to be able to start to implement the solution ?

Comment: How to set cronjob ? https://blog.cpanel.com/how-to-configure-a-cron-job/

Comment: How to send emails with php with mail() function - https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-send-email.php#:~:text=%3C%3F-,php%20%24to%20%3D%20'maryjane%40email.com'%3B,%2F%2F%20Create%20email%20headers%20%24headers%20.

Comment: How to send php email with phpmailer ? - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-an-email-using-phpmailer/

Comment: How to update database ? for email_sent=0 TO email_sent=1 ? https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-update-query.php

Comment: Hello Manish, I have coding experience but not in this techno. may you help me to implement the solution ? would you be available for gotomeeting session ?

Comment: Hello - I am looking for some help to implement the solution as I am fresher on the PHP coding language - I can pay you - You can contact me on etrables@gmail.com

Comment: plz check your email

Comment: Dear Manish - I have checked my email : etrables@gmail.com - I got nothing from you.

Comment: i resent email.. plz check or whapp on +919881150272